Not Able to Install `libgdal-dev` on Ubuntu 22.04 Due to Unmet Dependencies
I'm encountering issues while trying to install the libgdal-dev package on an ARM-based server running Ubuntu 22.04. The installation fails due to unmet dependencies with several libraries. Below are the details of the error message I receive:
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libexpat1-dev : Depends: libexpat1 (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2) but 2.4.7-1ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
 libtiff-dev : Depends: libtiff5 (= 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.7) but 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.9 is to be installed
 libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3) but 2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

My Current Setup:

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 (ARM architecture)
Server Provider: Hetzner Online
libexpat1 version: 2.4.7-1ubuntu0.3 (installed)
libtiff5 version: 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.9 (installed)
libxml2 version: 2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.4 (installed)

The required versions of these libraries are:

libexpat1 (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2)
libtiff5 (= 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.7)
libxml2 (= 2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3)

Steps I’ve Tried:

Updated the package list with sudo apt-get update and cleaned the cache using sudo apt-get clean.
Attempted to downgrade the versions of libexpat1, libtiff5, and libxml2 to match the required versions using sudo apt-get install libexpat1=2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2 (also tried with other packages), but encountered 404 Not Found errors.
Verified the available versions using apt-cache policy and confirmed that the required versions are listed in the repository, but are not retrievable.

Question:

Is there a reliable way to resolve these dependency conflicts and successfully install libgdal-dev on Ubuntu 22.04 for ARM?
Is there an alternative method to obtain and install the required versions of these libraries?
Has anyone experienced similar issues on ARM architecture, and how did you overcome them?

Any assistance or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated, as this issue is blocking further progress on my project.
Thank you!
More details:
Output of apt policy for the affected packages:
$ apt policy libtiff5 libtiff-dev
libtiff5:
  Installed: 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.9
  Candidate: 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.9
  Version table:
 *** 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.9 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.3.0-6ubuntu0.7 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main arm64 Packages
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/main arm64 Packages
     4.3.0-6 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 Packages
libtiff-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.7
  Version table:
     4.3.0-6ubuntu0.7 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main arm64 Packages
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/main arm64 Packages
     4.3.0-6 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 Packages

Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list:
I am using a mix of Hetzner and Ubuntu ports repositories:
deb http://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu-ports/packages jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse


It may help to share your sources.list - I don't see the mentioned versions anywhere in the official repos. For example libtiff5/libtiff-dev are plain 4.3.0-6 for both arm64 and armhf according to packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libtiff-dev. The outputs of apt policy may be helpful here (e.g. apt policy libtiff5 libtiff-dev etc.).

@steeldriver question edited. It looks like there are some version mismatches in the Hetzner mirrors compared to the official Ubuntu repositories. I'm not sure if that's the root cause or if there's something else going on.

Resolved: Package Version Issues Due to Mirror Problems
Issue:
I discovered that I had installed package versions that were no longer available in the repositories. This situation arose due to problems with the Hetzner mirror (as noted in their status page: https://status.hetzner.com/incident/9ea719cc-5ef5-46cf-b286-a76c10da5492). Consequently, several packages had unmet dependencies, preventing me from installing or upgrading certain software.
Solution:

Ignore the jammy-updates Repository: Since the versions in jammy-updates were unavailable, I removed the jammy-updates and jammy-security repositories from my sources list.

Downgrade Affected Packages: I created a script to automatically downgrade the packages with dependency issues to the versions available in the jammy repository. Alternatively, this can be done manually for each package by checking the available version using apt policy and running:
sudo apt-get install "package=available_version" --allow-downgrades -y



Here is my bash script to automate the process:
(Note: First, create a text file containing the packages you want to downgrade.)
#!/bin/bash

# Read packages from the file
while IFS= read -r package; do
    # Get the available version from the repository
    available_version=$(apt-cache policy "$package" | grep -A3 'Version table:' | grep '500' | awk '{print $1}')
    
    if [ -n "$available_version" ]; then
        echo "Downgrading $package to version $available_version..."
        sudo apt-get install "$package=$available_version" --allow-downgrades -y
    else
        echo "No available version found for $package."
    fi
done < packages.txt

